# Join select query from 2 tables

Tags: postgresql, express

Given two tables (in the same DB):
[image]

[image]

I would like to query a list of results from both tables WHERE environment = qa/staging ordered by **time**

I am using Postgres DB and express server.

Expected results :

```
build | qa | 2020-09-04 18:01:04.425261 | true 
test  | qa | 2020-09-04 22:46:50.862843 | @signUpHappyPath | 35530 | true
test  | qa | 2020-09-04 22:50:30.256647 | @passwordStrength| 6877  | true
build | qa | 2020-09-05 01:15:44.063051 | false
test  | qa | 2020-09-05 01:20:54.900635 | @shortseq        | 74450 | false
```

Comment: Can you share the expected result?

Comment: SELECT * FROM <first_table_name> a, <second_table_name> b WHERE a.environment = b.environment ORDER BY time [DESC | ASC];

Comment: @Mureinik thanks for the correct comment, results added

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the following SQL should work to **join the 2 tables on the "environment" field**, limit the results to where the environment field is either "qa" or "staging", and then sort by time in ascending order:

```
SELECT Tab1.*, Tab2.*
FROM YourTableOne AS Tab1, YourTableTwo AS Tab2
WHERE (Tab1.environment = Tab2.environment)
AND ((Tab1.environment = 'qa') OR (Tab1.environment = 'staging'))
ORDER BY Tab1.time
```

Alternatively, **join the 2 tables on the "time" field**, limit the results to where the environment field is either "qa" or "staging", and then sort by time in ascending order:

```
SELECT Tab1.*, Tab2.*
FROM YourTableOne AS Tab1, YourTableTwo AS Tab2
WHERE (Tab1.time = Tab2.time)
AND ((Tab1.environment = 'qa') OR (Tab1.environment = 'staging'))
ORDER BY Tab1.time
```

Comment: BTW, there is data in the expected results posted by the OP that does not match what is shown in their included screenshots of the two tables. So that adds to the confusion.